# How to see from the terminal what file I am downloading from Firefox or Chrome

Tags: command-line, firefox, downloads

I want to see from the terminal what file I am downloading from Firefox or Chrome. Is there a way to monitor what files I am downloading from the terminal?

Note that I want to see this WHILE downloading it. A way to see what is being downloaded while doing the download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are downloading a file in Chrome you can go to the download directory and search for files that have the *.crdownload* postfix. After download is finished the file is being renamed and the postfix is removed.

In Firefox the mechanism is very similar and the extension *.part* is being added.

Comment: It should be while downloading. Not after. I want to see what file I am downloading. Does not help, at least in my case if I want to see the file after I downloaded it.

Comment: @Luis you should try this answer, it's correct.